# PDO query to local sqlite file returns "No such Table" error SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: sqlite, pdo

Trying to select data into php page running on local Mac MAMP environment from sqlite file of my Things database.

Both DB connection & select code below and Things.sqlite files are located in same directory on the machine.

Getting "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: TMTask" error though there's clearly such table as visible on the screenshot of viewing file in Base app.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuUv9.png)

```
<?php

try {
    $db = new PDO("sqlite:".__DIR__."Things.sqlite3");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Unable to connect to database";
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

try {
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * from TMTask");
    echo "Retrieved results.";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Unable to retrieve results: ".$e->getMessage();
    //exit;
}

var_dump($results->fetchAll());
```

?>

Comment: always debug your code. var_dump("sqlite:".__DIR__."Things.sqlite3"); see what file it tries to open and then fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @your-common-sense! It helped. I figured out there was missing "/" in the file path.